How to preprocess observations for a DQN agent in Stable Baselines3?
I'm working on a reinforcement learning project using the Stable Baselines3 library to train a DQN agent on the Breakout-v4 environment from OpenAI Gym. I've written some code to preprocess the observations, but I'm facing an issue with the input shape of the model.
Code:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium import Wrapper
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, Permute
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import CheckpointCallback
from collections import deque

IMG_SHAPE = (84, 84)
WINDOW_LENGTH = 4
INPUT_SHAPE = (WINDOW_LENGTH, IMG_SHAPE[0], IMG_SHAPE[1])
LIMIT = 10000

class ImageProcessorWrapper(gym.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, env, img_shape=(84, 84), window_length=4, reward_clipping=(-1, 1)):
        super().__init__(env)
        self.img_shape = img_shape
        self.reward_clipping = reward_clipping
        self.window_length = window_length
        self.frames = deque(maxlen=window_length)

    def process_observation(self, observation):
        if isinstance(observation, tuple):
            observation = observation[0]
        img = Image.fromarray(observation)
        img = img.resize(self.img_shape)
        img = img.convert('L')
        return np.array(img)

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        observation = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
        if isinstance(observation, tuple):
            observation = observation[0]
        processed_observation = self.process_observation(observation)
        for _ in range(self.window_length):
            self.frames.append(processed_observation)
        return np.stack(self.frames, axis=0)

    def step(self, action):
        observation, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)
        if isinstance(observation, tuple):
            observation = observation[0]
        processed_observation = self.process_observation(observation)
        self.frames.append(processed_observation)
        return np.stack(self.frames, axis=0), np.clip(reward, *self.reward_clipping), done

# Create and wrap the environment
env = gym.make('BreakoutDeterministic-v4')
env = ImageProcessorWrapper(env, img_shape=(84, 84), window_length=4)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])

# Define your model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Permute((2, 3, 1), input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (8, 8), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(env.action_space.n, activation='linear'))

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.00025), loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

agent = DQN(
    'CnnPolicy',
    env,
    learning_rate=1e-4,
    buffer_size=10000,  # Reduce the buffer size to 30,000
    learning_starts=1000,
    batch_size=16,
    target_update_interval=1000,
    exploration_initial_eps=1.0,
    exploration_fraction=0.1,
    exploration_final_eps=0.02,
    train_freq=4,
    gradient_steps=1,
    gamma=0.99,
    verbose=1
)

checkpoint_callback = CheckpointCallback(save_freq=10000, save_path='./models/', name_prefix='dqn_breakout')

agent.learn(total_timesteps=1000000, callback=checkpoint_callback)

The input shape of the model is (WINDOW_LENGTH, IMG_SHAPE[0], IMG_SHAPE[1]), which is (4, 84, 84). However, when I try to train the DQN agent, I'm getting an error related to the input shape:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "permute_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 4, 84, 84)

Desired Outcome:
I would like to successfully train the DQN agent on the Breakout-v4 environment using the preprocessed observations.
Attempts:
I've tried adjusting the input shape of the model, but I'm still encountering issues. I'm not sure if I'm missing something in the way I'm preprocessing the observations.
Environment:

Python 3.9

Stable Baselines3 1.5.0

TensorFlow 2.9.1

OpenAI Gym 0.26.2

PIL 9.3.0

NumPy 1.23.5


